# Grow/resize RAID when upgrading visible size of disks

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

I originally created a software RAID using a controller that could only address 2TB per disk. The disks are 3 TB disks. It worked fine, but only used the first 2TB of each disk.

I have now changed the controller to see the full 3TB. I would therefore like `/dev/md0` to use the last 1 TB, too.

I have tried:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
mdadm: component size of /dev/md0 has been set to 2147479552K
```

But as you can see it only sees the 2TB. If I try forcing it higher:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=2147483648
mdadm: Cannot set device size for /dev/md0: No space left on device
```

So somehow the system can see the disks are 3TB (in `/proc/partitions`), but the RAID cannot see them as 3TB.

## mdadm details:

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
    Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Fri Mar  2 15:14:46 2012
 Raid Level : raid6
 Array Size : 38654631936 (36863.93 GiB 39582.34 GB)
Used Dev Size : 2147479552 (2048.00 GiB 2199.02 GB)
Raid Devices : 20
Total Devices : 21
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Wed Apr 25 19:47:09 2012
      State : active
Active Devices : 20
Working Devices : 21
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 1

     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 4096K

       Name : node5:1
       UUID : 8603c3df:b740ba22:8c9c82fd:a18b3133
     Events : 845

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
  20      65       32        0      active sync   /dev/sds
   1      65       64        1      active sync   /dev/sdu
   2      65       80        2      active sync   /dev/sdv
   3      65       96        3      active sync   /dev/sdw
   4       8      192        4      active sync   /dev/sdm
   5       8       32        5      active sync   /dev/sdc
   6       8       48        6      active sync   /dev/sdd
   7       8       64        7      active sync   /dev/sde
   8       8       80        8      active sync   /dev/sdf
   9       8       96        9      active sync   /dev/sdg
  10       8      112       10      active sync   /dev/sdh
  11       8      128       11      active sync   /dev/sdi
  12       8      144       12      active sync   /dev/sdj
  13       8      160       13      active sync   /dev/sdk
  14       8      176       14      active sync   /dev/sdl
  15       8      208       15      active sync   /dev/sdn
  16       8      224       16      active sync   /dev/sdo
  17       8      240       17      active sync   /dev/sdp
  18      65        0       18      active sync   /dev/sdq
  19      65       16       19      active sync   /dev/sdr

  21      65       48        -      spare   /dev/sdt
```

## Disk sizes:

```
# cat /proc/partitions |grep 2930266584
   8       48 2930266584 sdd
   8       32 2930266584 sdc
   8      112 2930266584 sdh
   8       96 2930266584 sdg
   8       80 2930266584 sdf
   8      128 2930266584 sdi
   8      176 2930266584 sdl
   8       64 2930266584 sde
  65       32 2930266584 sds
   8      192 2930266584 sdm
   8      144 2930266584 sdj
  65       80 2930266584 sdv
   8      224 2930266584 sdo
   8      208 2930266584 sdn
   8      160 2930266584 sdk
   8      240 2930266584 sdp
  65        0 2930266584 sdq
  65       64 2930266584 sdu
  65       16 2930266584 sdr
  65       48 2930266584 sdt
  65       96 2930266584 sdw
```

Edit:

```
# mdadm --version
mdadm - v3.1.4 - 31st August 2010
# uname -a
Linux lemaitre 3.2.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 11 08:41:32 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The RAID6 uses the full disks (i.e. no partitions)

This morning the system crashed. After a reboot the system did not find the RAID (which was terrible). All disks showed up as spares (S):

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
md0 : inactive sdr[20](S) sds[21](S) sdq[18](S) sdp[17](S) sdo[16](S) sdn[15](S) sdl[14](S) sdk[13](S) sdj[12](S) sdi[11](S) sdh[10](S) sdg[9](S) sdf[8](S) sde[7](S) sdd[6](S) sdc[5](S) sdm[4](S) sdv[3](S) sdu[2](S) sdt[1](S)
      42949652460 blocks super 1.2
```

Even here it is clear that `mdadm` did not find the 3 TB size.

I ran `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`. Removed the entry in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf. Ran 
`mdadm -A --scan --force`, which caused the RAID to come online and rebuild.

Comment: You are using 20 whole disks for RAID6 - correct? There is no partition on each disk? What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdd` show? What OS are you using, what is the mdadm-version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I poked around /sys and got a lot closer to the answer.

```
# cd /sys/block/md0/md
# cat component_size
2147479552
```

That agrees with what we have seen before. But this:

```
# grep . dev-sd*/size
dev-sdc/size:2147482623
dev-sdd/size:2147482623
dev-sde/size:2147482623
dev-sdf/size:2930265560
dev-sdg/size:2147482623
dev-sdh/size:2147482623
dev-sdi/size:2147482623
dev-sdj/size:2147482623
dev-sdk/size:2147482623
dev-sdl/size:2147483648
dev-sdm/size:2147482623
dev-sdn/size:2147482623
dev-sdo/size:2147482623
dev-sdp/size:2147482623
dev-sdq/size:2147482623
dev-sdr/size:2147482623
dev-sds/size:2147482623
dev-sdt/size:2147482623
dev-sdu/size:2147482623
dev-sdv/size:2147482623
dev-sdw/size:2930265560
```

seems to explain why the RAID sees the wrong size: Most of the drives shows up as 2TB while the 2 that have been replaced shows up as 3TB. All the drives are the same model, so let us see, if we can change the perceived size:

```
# parallel echo 2930265560 \> ::: dev-sd*/size
# grep . dev-sd*/size
dev-sdc/size:2930265560
dev-sdd/size:2930265560
dev-sde/size:2930265560
dev-sdf/size:2930265560
dev-sdg/size:2930265560
dev-sdh/size:2930265560
dev-sdi/size:2930265560
dev-sdj/size:2930265560
dev-sdk/size:2930265560
dev-sdl/size:2930265560
dev-sdm/size:2930265560
dev-sdn/size:2930265560
dev-sdo/size:2930265560
dev-sdp/size:2930265560
dev-sdq/size:2930265560
dev-sdr/size:2930265560
dev-sds/size:2930265560
dev-sdt/size:2930265560
dev-sdu/size:2930265560
dev-sdv/size:2930265560
dev-sdw/size:2930265560
```

Voila. Component_size is still small, though:

```
# cat component_size
2147479552
```

Maybe it can be changed by mdadm:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
```

This unfortunately locks up `mdadm` and subsequent access to /dev/md0 is blocked. And so is access to component_size:

```
# cat component_size   # This blocks
```

Sucks. But the good part is that in syslog it says:

```
Apr 27 20:45:50 server kernel: [124731.725019] md0: detected capacity change from 39582343102464 to 54010589478912
```

The filesystem on /dev/md0 still ran.

After a reboot I had to do 'mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max' again. Then wait for `resync` to complete. Again access to /dev/md0 was blocked. So yet another reboot, followed by `xfs_growfs /dev/md0` and then the resize was complete.

Comment: I thoroughly liked the parallel(1) plug, Ole :)  Thanks for the investigation, just hit a similar case.

Comment: I guess "mdadm --update=devicesize" would do it too, see man page: "This will cause mdadm to determine the maximum usable amount of space on each device and update the relevant field in the metadata."

Answer (score 3):

I think during creation the size of the device was registered somewhere in the metadata. Changing the controller doesn't change the metadata.

Remove the spare from the md, then re-add it to the RAID set as a new drive. You probably have to remove the metadata (check man page for --zero-superblock or wipe the whole disk). If that works for a single disk, repeat the procedure for all remainind drives too. Then finally do the --grow.

Don't remove additional disks until the sync finished!!

Comment: It is unclear to me if you have tested that this actually works. A rebuild takes around 1.5 days. Replacing all 20 drives will cause running degraded for a full month. When you write "If that works for a single disk" how do you test that it worked for the single disk?

Comment: No I haven't tested this, but I've seen some md problems before and I have some feeling about how it works ... and fails. I don't have the drives with bad metadata lying around to test it. I'm aware of the long sync time, that is why I advise to use the spare. You have RAID6, which means 2 drives can fail and you have a spare. That means a total of 3 drives that can fail before you have a problem. You could check with a single drive, at least you know if this is your issue. I have only limited information about your setup. Don't pull drives from your RAID set if you're not comfortable doing it

Comment: Oh, I understand your question. mdadm will warn you that you're trying to add a device that is much larger than the other ones. It doesn't mind about a few bytes, but it warns you when it the difference is relatively large.

Comment: Is there not any other way to rewrite the meta-data?

Comment: You can `fail` a drive, then `remove` it, then `zero-superblock` it to remove the metadata. As your RAID set is in use you can either add it as a spare, which means it won't sync until another drive fails (that is normal behavior) but it only works for a single drive OR you `add` it and it requires a sync. I know it takes forever. Or you accept the fact that you cannot addres all storage available. One of the advantages of using a partition table which you didn't. Not using a partition table is not bad, but in this particular case would have helped you.

Comment: You have up to 36T data stored, please be careful and make backups.

Comment: @jippie "you could check with a single drive" How do I see if it was successful for the single drive? What output of what command will tell me that the added drive did in fact get the correct meta-data written? I will feel like a fool if I risk downtime (yes: I have had 1 disk go bad in a RAID6, before the previous rebuild was complete) and impair performance for a full month just to discover that it was all for nothing.

Comment: See my comment above: "mdadm will warn you that you're trying to add a device that is much larger than the other ones."

Comment: I have failed a drive. Replaced it with another 3TB disk. Rebuild is done. I have added the 3TB disk as spare. mdadm did not warn about anything.

Comment: Strange, I'm sure having seen warning when I was replacing disks. I exchanged my 750GB drives with 1TB drives about a year ago. Does `sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdx` give proper results?